# M1 MacBook Pro has problems with holding an internet connection after Ventura upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, internet

My M1 MacBook Pro has been working great with my home network -- until I upgraded to Ventura.  Now, it seems to connect every 15-30 seconds, disconnects, and then reconnects to the network.

ISP: Comcast
Modem: Netgear CM600
Router: Orbi  RBR50

Other devices on my network have no problem.  I called Comcast and they reset the modem and couldn't find any other problems with it at their end.  The wifi signal stays strong, so I don't think that's what's failing. I'm not using a VPN.

I've tried restarting wifi, changing the DNS, renewing the DHCP lease, rebooting,  reinstalling Ventura, and connecting to a different network (at the library).

I called Apple support and they had no other suggestions. I thought I'd reset the SMC or PRAM, but I now know the M1 Macs no longer have those.

I'm out of ideas.